# GCP vm firewall block all incoming port but 80. How SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, firewall

I ssh to GCP Centos vm instance by port 22 but I run firewall-cmd script to block all incoming port except 80. Now I cannot ssh to connect my vm instance due to port 22 is blocked. Is there any solution to allow ssh again because I can not do anything. Please help.

Sincerely
Bom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) with the firewall-cmd commands you need to have the port 22 opened and then apply it to your instance.